# PHP Problems Combining implode() with mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, implode

How do I correctly write the code for a MySQL query that both implodes and mysql_real_escape_string?

This is the code that I have, but it's failing:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO BEER_LOCATIONS 
        (LOCATION_NAME, LOCATION_STREET, LOCATION_CITY, LOCATION_STATE,
        LOCATION_ZIPCODE, LOCATION_PHONE, BEER_STYLE ) 
    VALUES 
        ('" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode("', '", $row)) . "')";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
implode("', '", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row))
```

This applies `mysql_real_escape_string` to every element in `$row` and returns an array with the escaped values to `implode`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a very old question, Google still brought me here, so maybe my solution will be helpful to someone else:

When trying to use the MySQLi version of mysql_real_escape_string, you'll realise that array_map can't handle the two parameters required for mysqli_real_escape_string. Hence you have to wrap it in a function that only takes one parameter:

```
function arrayEscaper($val){
   global $link;
   return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $val);
 };
```

Then you can use that function in array_map like so:

```
$myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
$myArrayEsc = array_map('arrayEscaper', $myArray);
$myString = implode(", ", $myArrayEsc);
```

Hope this helps.